# Conditioning a while loop (2 conditions)

Tags: r, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to include two conditions in a `while` loop:

1. the first condition is the number of simulations must be at least
   50
2. the second condition is the std(estimator) must be less than
       0.01.

Can someone help me ?

```
set.seed(1)
MinSimNumber=50
Ncount=0
n=0
N=rep(0,10000)
sqrt(var(N))
while(Ncount<MinSimNumber){
  u=runif(40,0,1) #Generating a big enough vector
if(u[n+1]>u[n+2]){  #if the preceding uniform value is bigger than execute the loop
  while(u[n+1]>u[n+2]){ #while the  preceding uniform value is bigger than the following than do n=n+1
  n=n+1

  }
  n=n+2 #when the loop ends we do n=n+2 to add the first two not counted values 
}

if((u[n+1]<=u[n+2])&(n==0)) {
  n=2
}
  Ncount=Ncount+1
  N[Ncount]=n
  n=0
}
```

Here is my complete code this simulation approximate the exp(1)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! It would greatly facilitate our capacity to help you if you would edit your question so that is provides a [minimal reproducible example].(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
while(Ncount<100 & sqrt(var(N))<0.01)        
{        
  Ncount=Ncount+1        
  # (all my other statements...)        
}
```

or this if you have to do 100 steps even if the std is higher than 0.01

```
while(sqrt(var(N))<0.01)        
{        
  if(Ncount<100)        
  {        
    Ncount=Ncount+1        
    # (all my other statements...)        
    }        
  Ncount=Ncount+1        
  # (all my other statements...)        
  }
```

of course you can define "100" and "0.01" before the while loop

for your edit:

```
while(Ncount<100)        
{        
    Ncount=Ncount+1        
    # (all my other statements...)        
}        
if(sqrt(var(N))<0.01){TRUE}else{FALSE}
```